# kryo list serialization

Tags: java, list, serialization, constructor, kryo

I am trying to serialize a List of List of some objects (of a customized class: List> ), using Kryo.

```
list2D; // List<List<MyClass>> which is already produced.

Kryo k1 = new Kryo();
Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream("filename.ser"));
k1.writeObject(output, (List<List<Myclass>>) list2D);
output.close();
```

So far no problem, it writes out the list with no errors. 
But when I try to read it:

```
Kryo k2 = new Kryo();
Input listRead = new Input(new FileInputStream("filename.ser"));
List<List<Myclass>> my2DList = (List<List<Myclass>>) k2.readObject(listRead,  List.class);
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): java.util.List
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `List.class` when read objects back, since `List` is an interface.

```
k2.readObject(listRead,  ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: You're right. And we don't need to cast. Ie: `List<Fabri> data = kryo.readObject(input, ArrayList.class);`

Answer (score 2):

According to your error, you might want to add a no-arg constructor to your class:

```
 public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {  // no-arg constructor

    }

    //Rest of your class..

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But MyClass already has a constructor which takes one String argument. Any ideas?

Comment: Add zero arg constructor or write your own serializer to create the object. You can extend FieldSerializer and override create.